# moment construction falls back to js Date

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, momentjs, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using `daterangepicker` with `moment` for selecting different range. I need to set `startDate` and `endDate` dynamically.

In `html.erb` file:

```
<%if params[:campaign_report].present? && params[:campaign_report]["daterange"].present?%>
  <%date_range= params[:campaign_report]["daterange"].split("-")%>
  <%= @start_date= Date.parse(date_range[0]).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")%>
  <%= @end_date= Date.parse(date_range[1]).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")%>
<%else%>
  <%= @start_date= Date.parse(@daterange).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")%>
  <%= @end_date= Date.parse(@daterange).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")%>
<%end%>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
  function report_form_submit(start, end) {
    $('#daterange').val(start.format('MMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMM D, YYYY'));
    $("#campaign_report_daterange").val($("#daterange").val())
    $("#daily_filter_form").submit();
  }

  $('#daterange').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    startDate: moment('<%= @start_date%>'),
    endDate: moment('<%= @end_date%>')
  }, report_form_submit);
});
.....
```

I am getting warning in browser console like:

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

Comment: that's a warning, not an error, but you should do something about it - are you showing the **whole** message or just the first part?

Comment: because the **whole** warning includes a link, `https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407` ... which tells you **exactly** how to fix it

Comment: Follow the link and fix your code ^^^ see how I knew the whole message before you revealed all in your question? That makes me a wizard - should I be burned at the stake for this demonic power?

Comment: I already followed the link but it is not working only when setting value for both `startDate` and `endDate` dynamically.

Comment: I can not see in the code you posted where you have addressed the issue in any manner suggested in the link - ensure an ISO conformant date, or supply an expected date format as an argument to moment

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction given in the link in the warning: use moment parsing specifying format.

As the docs says:

> Warning: Browser support for parsing strings [is inconsistent](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

In your case you have to use:

```
startDate: moment('<%= @start_date%>', 'YYYY/MM/DD'),
endDate: moment('<%= @end_date%>', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```